# Height of Thumbnails change dynamically as more are added/removed to fit into their parent DIV

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, dynamic, height

I have looked into all the suggested articles and they seem to address the oposite of what i would like to do. instead of a dynamic 'DIV' I need the said container to be fixed in size and the content of said container to adjust in height to fit into the div based off the quantity of content. I need it to work with images, not text though.

specifically, i have a div that contains the thumnails of a post on a 'single page' for wordpress site. I want the user to be able to add 20 thumbnails, or maybe 10, or maybe 100. but no matter how many they add, the height of the thumnails will adjust so they all fit into a pre defined 'div'.

So, in other words, i need the height of my thumbnails to be a percentage of the height of the containing div, divided by the number of thumnails...i think

example photos include a before and after of the effect im looking for:
I am already using jquery to do some hover animations so there is already a script framework set up.
I just dont know how to get started doing something like this.

thank you!

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/azUM8, the url to the images. it didnt show up in the question. i must of had a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code that will modify height of each image so that sum of all height will be the desired height of the cotainer:

```
// all image tags inside the container
var images = $('#container').find('img');
// desired height of the container (you can use also data- attribute)
var height = 400;
images.each(function() {
    // let's say 600 is the original width of the image
    $(this).css('width', '600px');
    // modify height of the image
    $(this).css('height', height / images.length + 'px');
});
```

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/gtpDu/)** is a working example supporting add/remove and using a custom event.

Comment: this works wonderfully. im just trying to get the results to play nice with my style sheet now. thank you so much!

Comment: @JosephCampbell You did :). Glad to help!

Comment: update:   i changed the math to:                             [(height - images.length)/images.length]    ....this gives a 1px margin between the thumbs without any css.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this without javascript using css3 flexbox, but you would these are only supported by Webkit browsers and Firefox. Your css would look like:

```
#container {
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: box;
  height: 500px;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  box-orient: vertical;
}

#container div {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
}
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/NtVTY/ (javascript is just for illustration purposes).

But, alas, I wouldn't recommend using it, it's just a coding exercise :)

Comment: this is very good to know. more soon than later this will be a standard option. I didnt even know it existed obviously.